# Mapping mouse rocker motions in gvim for windows?

Tags: vim

I have my web browser set up to switch tabs using rocker motions, and I'd like to do the same for gvim. A rocker gesture is just clicking RMB then LMB (while RMB is held) to switch to the previous tab, and the reverse for the next tab.

This mapping works to switch to the previous tab:

```
:nnoremap <RightMouse><LeftMouse> gT
```

However, **in my gvim, the default LMB->RMB behaviour seems to be performing a middle-click** (pasting text). When I put in the command to change it...

```
:nnoremap <LeftMouse><RightMouse> gt
```

it keeps pasting instead of switching tabs.

Mapping `<MiddleMouse>` to `<nop>` stops the pasting, but the tabs still don't switch. But mapping `<LeftMouse><RightMouse>` to `<nop>` *doesn't* stop the pasting. Could the `<LeftMouse><RightMouse>` motion be getting mapped to middle-click at some deeper level?

I checked, and `<LeftMouse>` has no other mappings. Mapping it to `<nop>` didn't help either.

Any ideas? Keep in mind the motion works in my browser.

Comment: I'm not sure you can chain these. My tests seem to suggest that if you can't